# Unable to start daemon process i have tried many things.. i'm using android 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle.properties

Here is the Error..

Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

---

I have tried these steps but dosnt work for me ..

1.change gradle.properties...org.gradle.jvmargs=-xmx1536m to 1024 value and 51... something like that..

2. after that i try to delete my .gradle folder which is of 1.5gb apprx..

3.Restart and open ..

4. invalidate cache and restart
5. go to configuration and change heap size...

But no solution work for me ... please help

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution ?